# How to save a lifetimes model file (.pkl) in Azure

Tags: azure, pickle

I have an Azure notebook in which I've created a lifetimes GammaGamma model.  If I were to run the same notebook locally, I can save the model easily using

```
model.save_model('model.pkl')
```

But I am not sure how to create the same pickled model file in Azure so it can be accessed/loaded from other notebooks.  Can I save it to dbfs or some storage container?  If so, could someone please help me with the commands?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload your model.pkl file to Azure Storage account container as a blob and then use the same blob as a data store in your Machine learning or import the same model to your ML workspace Model like below:-

***Go to your ML Workspace > Assets > Data > data store > select workspaceblobstore (Default) > Account name is your storage account name> Browse datastore and copy the storage account container name that is used by the workspace by default like below:-***

[image]

**Container name:-**

[image]

***Visit your Azure Portal and open the same storage account above and copy the connection string from Access Keys and container name and add it in the code below:-***

> I uploaded a Blob to my storage account with the code below referred from this [MS  Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-upload-python):-

```py
from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

import  pickle

  

# Load the model

model = ...

  

# Serialize the model

model_bytes = pickle.dumps(model)

  

# Create a BlobServiceClient object

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=strgaccountname;AccountKxxxxxxxxxxxxxJmQ6PaFABfUtCWjXOFERBkKDxBnDVHkwC+AStjnjy8Q==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net")

  

# Create a ContainerClient object

container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("container")

  

# Upload the pickled model file to Azure Blob Storage

blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client("model.pkl")

blob_client.upload_blob(model_bytes)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

***Go to your ML Workspace > Assets > Models > Register > from datastore > Select your storage account and model***

[image]

***workspaceblobstore (Default)  will be selected by default > select your model.pkl like below:-***

[image]

***Add name, description and version for your model:-***

[image]

**Register your model:-**

[image]

***Model got added like below:-***

[image]

> You can also register your model directly in your ML workspace from local file or using above data store method by using the python SDK code in this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-manage-models?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=cli,use-local#register-your-model-as-an-asset-in-machine-learning-by-using-the-sdk)